# Is "database indexing" possible on a C# List?

Tags: c#, list, performance, indexing

I have a `IList<Node>` in C#, and a `Node` is an object, having `Name` as a property.

Regularly, I need to perform a search inside that `IList<Node>`, which I do as follows:

```
List_of_Nodes.Where(o => o.Name == "Something").FirstOrDefault();
```

I would like to know if there is a way to speed that up.
In a database, a search within a table can be executed faster by creating an index on the column you want to search on.

Is that also possible in a C# `IList`?
(I've been looking on the site, but I always get results like `List_of_Nodes[index]`. It would be great it I could replace the search by `List_of_Nodes[name]`, but how can I achieve that?

Comment: _"I would like to know if there is a way to speed that up."_ -> Use a `Dictionary<string, YourType>` instead?

Comment: Do you have multiple properties to index? You can create a `Dictionary` for every one of them as needed. It is however *theoretically* possible to make a class that can manage indexes and implement `IQueryable` to read `Where(o => o.Name == "Something")` and execute that efficiently, but that could not be an `IList`.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you to learn about and follow .NET naming conventions as early as possible - best to get into good habits straight away instead of having to "unlearn" bad ones.

Comment: @Fildor What technique would you recommend for non-unique keys? While `Dictionary<String,List<YourType>>` would work it's not ideal - I'd love for there to be an in-memory equivalent of SQL's (usually B-Tree-based) non-unique `INDEX` objects supporting multiple-property fully-ordered tuples.

Comment: @Dai: `var lookup = nodeList.ToLookup(node => node.Name);` would be my starting point.

Comment: @Dai I wouldn't recommend one. For one, there is no indication OP's usecase includes non-unique keys and secondly: that's a use-case I would have to explore myself, first. My first idea, though would be something like an in-mem db... (?) maybe ...

Comment: @JonSkeet `ToLookup` can't be used to maintain ordering by a second property though (does it preserve input order at all, in fact?).

Comment: @Dai How is this related to the question at hand? Or are you just curious?

Comment: @Fildor Curious because I had a very similar problem to the OP a couple of weeks ago and I tried building my own in-memory B-tree-like system to allow `O(log n)` resolution of non-unique-but-sorted elements in another collection - but I couldn't get it work well so in-the-end I gave-up and stuck with dumb-but-works code which I'm not terribly proud of :)

Comment: @Dai: It maintains order within the results of each group. Not sure whether it preserves the order of the groups. But this really sounds like it should be a new question - it's quite a long way from what the OP has asked.

Comment: @JonSkeet: what naming conventions did I break in my question?

Comment: `List_of_Nodes` is a *very* unconventional name in .NET. I'd expect `nodeList` as a local variable, or `NodeList` as a property.

Comment: Is the `IList<Node>` mutable or frozen? I mean, are elements added or removed between subsequent searches?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: between searches, elements can be added or removed, this is all done within the same thread.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053483/11178549) by Dmitry Bychenko creates an index on a snapshot of the list. After mutating the list, the index is out of sync and should be rebuild. The cost of rebuilding the index is higher than performing a single search. So why did you accept that answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `Dictionary` as an index (which is similar to hash index in a database); let it be `Dictionary<string, Node[]>`: for given `Key`
we get an array of corresponding `Node`s:

```
// Build Dictionary based index
var myIndex = List_of_Nodes
  .GroupBy(node => node.Name)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToArray());

...

// Ask index if it has nodes with "Something" Name...
var result = myIndex.TryGetValue("Something", out var nodes)
  ? nodes[0] // ... if it has, obtain the 1st one
  : null;
```

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the presence of duplicates per key you can use [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0)(or hashset with custom comparer):

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

```cs
var indexByName = nodeList.ToDictionary(n => n.Name);
// or 
var indexByName = nodeList
   .GroupBy(n => n.Name)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First()); // or g => g.ToArray()
```

And access the value by key via indexer (will throw if not present) or via `TryGetValue` method.

or [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-7.0):

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.
> A `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. The difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` maps keys to single values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` maps keys to collections of values.

```
var indexByName = nodeList.ToLookup(node => node.Name);
```

And use indexer to access the data by `key`, if the `key` is not found in the collection, an empty sequence is returned.

Notes:

- Both can be considered as equivalent of [Hash indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-HASH), to simulate other types of indexes (like B-Tree) you will need to use other data structures.
- Both `To...` methods allows to specify comparer, for example to support case insensitive comparison - `nodeList.ToLookup(n => n.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`